# HTTP ERROR 405 when use django-oauth-login

Tags: django-rest-framework, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth

I want to make OAuth using Google and django rest framework, I use the django-oauth-login lib and made the steps in documentation.

made this file, oauth.py:

```py
import datetime
import requests
from django.utils import timezone
from oauthlogin.exceptions import OAuthError
from oauthlogin.providers import OAuthProvider, OAuthToken, OAuthUser


class GoogleOAuthProvider(OAuthProvider):
    authorization_url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth"

    google_token_url = "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token"
    google_user_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo"
    google_emails_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me/openIdConnect"

    def _get_token(self, request_data):
        response = requests.post(
            self.google_token_url,
            headers={
                "Accept": "application/json",
            },
            data=request_data,
        )
        response.raise_for_status()
        data = response.json()

        oauth_token = OAuthToken(
            access_token=data["access_token"],
        )

        # Expiration and refresh tokens are optional in Google depending on the app
        if "expires_in" in data:
            oauth_token.access_token_expires_at = timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(
                seconds=data["expires_in"]
            )

        if "refresh_token" in data:
            oauth_token.refresh_token = data["refresh_token"]

        if "refresh_token_expires_in" in data:
            oauth_token.refresh_token_expires_at = timezone.now() + datetime.timedelta(
                seconds=data["refresh_token_expires_in"]
            )

        return oauth_token

    def get_oauth_token(self, *, code, request):
        return self._get_token(
            {
                "client_id": self.get_client_id(),
                "client_secret": self.get_client_secret(),
                "code": code,
            }
        )

    def refresh_oauth_token(self, *, oauth_token):
        return self._get_token(
            {
                "client_id": self.get_client_id(),
                "client_secret": self.get_client_secret(),
                "refresh_token": oauth_token.refresh_token,
                "grant_type": "refresh_token",
            }
        )

    def get_oauth_user(self, *, oauth_token):
        response = requests.get(
            self.google_user_url,
            headers={
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Authorization": f"token {oauth_token.access_token}",
            },
        )
        response.raise_for_status()
        data = response.json()
        user_id = data["id"]
        username = data["login"]

        # Use the verified, primary email address (not the public profile email, which is optional anyway)
        response = requests.get(
            self.google_emails_url,
            headers={
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Authorization": f"token {oauth_token.access_token}",
            },
        )
        response.raise_for_status()

        try:
            verified_primary_email = [
                x["email"] for x in response.json() if x["primary"] and x["verified"]
            ][0]
        except IndexError:
            raise OAuthError("A verified primary email address is required on Google")

        return OAuthUser(
            id=user_id,
            email=verified_primary_email,
            username=username,
        )
```

and the settings.py

```py
OAUTH_LOGIN_PROVIDERS = {
    "google":{
        "class": "token_auth.oauth.GoogleOAuthProvider",
        "kwargs":{
            "client_id": env_vars["GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID"],
            "client_secret": env_vars["GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLEINT_SECRET"],
            # "scope": "email profile"
        }
    }
}
```

I run the endpoint/: `/oauth/google/login/` and got this:
[image]

The library has these endpoint:

```
oauth/ <str:provider>/ login/ [name='login'] 

oauth/ <str:provider>/ connect/ [name='connect']

oauth/ <str:provider>/ disconnect/ [name='disconnect']

oauth/ <str:provider>/ callback/ [name='callback']
```

why can't login?